# Convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)e^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: analysis

How to show the convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)e^{-x^2}dx$?

Where $p(x)$ is a polynomial.

This is a special case of the Gaußian Integral. Any help on this?

Comment: Let $m$ be the degree of the polynomial. Show that the Gaussian can be bounded above by $\frac{1}{x^{m+2}}$ away from zero.

Comment: Try to show it for $p(x)=x^n$ by induction and integration by parts and then sum up for a general polynomial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $x^n(1+x^2) < M_n e^{x^2}$ for some $M_n > 0$. Does that help?

Edit: This implies that $x^n  e^{-x^2}< M_n/ (1+x^2)$. So for any polynomial $P$ there is a constant $M_P > 0$ such that $|P(x) e^{-x^2}| < M_p/ (1+x^2)$. So you can compare and use that $\int 1/1+x^2 < \infty$.

Comment: That handles the case $P_n(x) = x^n (1+x^2)$, but I fail to see how knowing this one case solves the problem for all polynomials. It's obvious any polynomial will fail, but just from your example, how do we rigorously know there isn't another polynomial that IS an example? If I am missing something in your post, feel free to correct me!

Comment: Look at the edit. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Oh, OK. I see what you mean now! So you are showing that $x^n e^{-x^2}$ converges. The only nuance now is to show that the case $P_n(x) = x^n$ implies $P(x) = x^n + x^{n-1} +\cdots+x$ converges, but this is of course simple as we have a finite sum and can compare each term to $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Let me know if I am missing something, but it looks good now -- +1!

Comment: You are right !

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal Please check my answer. i am sure you will understand it.

Comment: Yes your answers seems right.

Answer (score 2):

Near $+\infty $,  for $\alpha>1$,We have always

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\color {red}{x^\alpha }p (x)e^{-x^2}=0$$
because exponential is faster.

thus for enough great $x $,

$$|\color {red}{x^\alpha}. p (x)e^{-x^2}|<1$$
or
$$|p (x)e^{-x^2}|<\frac {1}{\color {red}{x^\alpha}} $$

and by comparison criterion,
$$\int^{+\infty}p (x)e^{-x^2}dx $$ is convergent.

idem for $-\infty $.

Comment: Only thing you have to worry about is blow up before we reach infinity. Knowing end behavior does not guarantee this. A great example of this is $\sin(1/x)$, which can clearly be bounded as we go to $\pm \infty$. However, the integral does not converge! (In the classic sense of convergence)

Comment: Evidently I do not. However, this gives even more reason for you to explain your logic! If we know that $\left|P_n(x)e^{-x^2}\right| < x^{-2}$ for all $x \ge M$, then we can definitely say that $\int_M^\infty f(x) dx$ converges, but what about the other half of the integral, $\int_0^M f(x) dx$ ???

Comment: Which can definitely blow up? Case in point, $\int _0^1\frac{1}{x}dx$ diverges

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, since the integrand is continuous it can always be integrated on a bounded domain.

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal OK, with the edits I think I get what you're saying. I retract my downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P_n(x)\exp(-x^2)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-x^2)\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k\right) dx$$
Because we have finite summation, we can interchange the integral
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left(a_k \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-x^2)x^k \,dx\right)$$
The integral inside can be shown to be $\frac{1}{2} \left((-1)^k+1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)$, which is clearly convergent for any positive integers $k$. We conclude that the finite summation of convergent values (multiplied by some finite scalars) must be convergent.

Comment: how can I show this formula with the Gamma function?

Comment: @Averroes2 what do you mean? You want me to prove the evaluation of the integral? I'm more than happy to do that when I get a computer, but I'm afraid I'm on my phone right now. Give me 2-3 hours and I can prove it! In the mean time, I would accept Shubhodip's answer if you found it useful... It's a bit more elementary than mine, and does the job nicely (a bit of the argument was left out, but see my comments underneath his post for details)

Comment: OK thanks. Never seen it before

Comment: @Averroes2 The answer i gave is the most used for these integrals.